# Button returns to previous activity

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I've got this code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database;
EditText taryfaView;
EditText cenaZaMinView;
EditText mnoznikView;
EditText kwotaStartowaView;

DatabaseReference dataRef;
DatabaseReference dataUse;
User user;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    dataRef = database.getReference();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ustawienia);
    taryfaView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    cenaZaMinView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    mnoznikView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    kwotaStartowaView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);

    final Button buttonHaslo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final Button buttonTaryfa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
    final Button buttonKwota = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    final Button buttonMnoznik = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    final Button buttonCena = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    buttonHaslo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText hasloView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            String haslo = hasloView.getText().toString();
            if(!(haslo.equals(null) || haslo.equals(""))){
                dataUse = dataRef.child("UsersLogin").child(Logowanie.id).child("Password");
                dataUse.setValue(haslo);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

There are no errors in my debug log, what's wrong? After I type text in EditText and click button, it changes value in database, ok, but then it returns to previous activity..
logs (every line after clicking button):

```
> 08-22 14:25:03.951 7144-7254/com.example.xmisi3g.taxiapp D/FA: Logging
> event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=9345, _sc=Ustawienia,
> _si=8149823030479671449}] 08-22 14:25:03.958 7144-7144/com.example.xmisi3g.taxiapp I/Typeface: setThemeFont():
> sThemeFontPath = ,fontPath =  08-22 14:25:03.958
> 7144-7144/com.example.xmisi3g.taxiapp W/Typeface: setThemeFont():
> FontPath Not Changed! 08-22 14:25:03.994
> 7144-7144/com.example.xmisi3g.taxiapp D/lenovotintstatusbar: Check
> tint and icon theme, false, false 08-22 14:25:04.040
> 7144-7254/com.example.xmisi3g.taxiapp D/FA: Connected to remote
> service 08-22 14:25:04.067 7144-7144/com.example.xmisi3g.taxiapp
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
> 08-22 14:25:04.086 7144-7144/com.example.xmisi3g.taxiapp
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
> 08-22 14:25:04.086 7144-7144/com.example.xmisi3g.taxiapp
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive
> InputConnection 08-22 14:25:04.124
> 7144-7259/com.example.xmisi3g.taxiapp D/OpenGLRenderer:
> endAllStagingAnimators on 0x5574516c50 (RippleDrawable) with handle
> 0x5574290360 08-22 14:25:04.130 7144-7144/com.example.xmisi3g.taxiapp
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive
> InputConnection 08-22 14:25:04.131
> 7144-7144/com.example.xmisi3g.taxiapp W/IInputConnectionWrapper:
> getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection 08-22 14:25:04.132
> 7144-7144/com.example.xmisi3g.taxiapp W/IInputConnectionWrapper:
> endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

Please help, I've got no idea why does it happen
menu activity code:

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
}
public void Menu(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Ustawienia.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void Historia(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Historia.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void zajety(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Jazda.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}
Also sometimes in logs there is it:

```
08-22 14:33:03.668 10515-10949/com.example.xmisi3g.taxiapp I/FirebaseCrash: Sending crashes
```

but not always and there are not any crashes in firebase console
EDIT: Additional info, when onClickListener is empty it doesn't return to previous activity, so there's problem with onClickListener code, but I have no idea what, pls help

Comment: Can you post logs?

Comment: Can you post the activity code from where you are starting above activity?

Comment: please help....